# LINQ To Object - How To Group Based On Field

Tags: linq-to-objects

I am trying to use LINQ on my ObservableCollection to group some values in each object.  To keep things simple, suppose MyObject has one property:

```
public List<string> UserNames;
```

I want to write a LINQ query that returns all the strings in UserNames for each object in the collection – then group them all by the actual name.  I would like the end result to show each unique name and the count of how many times that name was found in the collection.

This is easy to do with T-Sql, but I’m not having any luck with Linq to Objects.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
var allUnique = myColl.SelectMany(x => x.UserNames).GroupBy(z=>z);

foreach (var s in allUnique )
{
    Console.WriteLine(s.Key.ToString() + " Count: " + s.Count().ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
collection.SelectMany(myObj => myObj.UserNames)
          .GroupBy(name => name)
          .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```